# MouseEvent to TouchEvent does not work in Adobe Flash Pro CC Simulator

Tags: actionscript-3, touch-event, flash-cc

I have programmed a simple game using Adobe Flash Pro CC coding in ActionScript 3.0.
As I'm developing it for Android, I changed all my listeners from MouseEvent to TouchEvent. The character is supposed to open his mouth when MOUSE_DOWN (TOUCH_BEGIN), but when I test the movie using the simulator (Control>Test / Control>Test Movie> in AIR Debug Launcher (mobile) ) touch events wont work.

Please tell me what's wrong!

Comment: And please notice although I'm using mouse to test my code, touch events must respond to mouse when testing Air for Android.

Comment: You actually don't have to use `TouchEvent`s, on a touch screen it will dispatch equivalent `MouseEvent`s when you touch the screen. The `TouchEvent`s are there if you need touch-specific behavior that doesn't convey with mouse events, like the touch size or distinguishing individual touch points during multi-touch.